# How can I access the "through" object of a Django ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models in my Django app. How can I from the `Team` model find all the `User` objects who have accepted as True in the Membership model? I know I need to use `Team.objects.filter()`, but I'm not sure how to check the value of the `accepted` field.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Team(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Membership")

class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted members of a team:

```
team_42.members.filter(membership__accepted=True)
```

Teams user `alice` has been accepted by:

```
alice.team_set.filter(membership__accepted=True)
```

I believe you want to get the set of Team or User objects and not the set of intermediate Membership objects.  You answered the question yourself but with an answer that gives the set of Membership objects.

Answer (score -1):

`Team.objects.filter(members__accepted__exact=True)`

Take a look at [this](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/). It has a lot of great examples and explanations.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'members_accepted' into field. Choices are: id, members, membership

Comment: Still doesn't work. FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'accepted' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, membership, message, password, team, user_permissions, username

Comment: @Macha: It looks like the issue is that you have Membership set up as an *intermediary* table; I'm not sure how a query for that would work. This might help you: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

The above query works fine for me if I set up the models without creating Membership as an intermediary table, like so:
http://www.pastie.org/878744

Comment: @VladtheImpala Sorry, but your example code doesn't make much sense. The Membership would be the many-to-many relation, why would you have a many-to-many relation *to* a Membership? Also, the link in the answer is dead now.